# Regex "\w" doesn't process utf-8 characters in Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9

Regex `\w` doesn't match utf-8 characters in Ruby 1.9.2. Anybody faced same problem?

Example:

```
/[\w\s]+/u
```

In my rails application.rb I've added `config.encoding = "utf-8"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define "doesn't match utf-8 characters"? If you expect `\w` to match anything other than exactly the uppercase and lowercase ASCII letters, the ASCII digits, and underscore, it won't -- Ruby has defined `\w` to be equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]` regardless of Unicode. Maybe you want `\p{Word}` or something similar instead.

Ref: [Ruby 1.9 Regexp documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html) (see section "Character Classes").

Comment: That works in .NET. Looks like it is a bug of ruby regex implementation

Comment: +1 Ruby has defined `\w` to be equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]` regardless of Unicode. It's so obvious, so neither I don't noticed :)

Comment: As the answerer states, `\p{Word}` does the job - but it's Ruby 1.9 only. Could be worth checking whether Regexp.instance_methods.include?(:encoding) to figure out what pattern you want to use.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference for the postulate "Ruby has defined \w to be equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_] regardless of Unicode."

Comment: @Jarl amended my answer. I can't find a definitive source for 1.8, but the meaning of `\w` in Ruby hasn't changed since... ever.

Comment: OK, as the answer states, the [Ruby 1.9 Regexp documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html) states that the shorthand `\w` is identical to `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and is non-portable (across alphabets/encodings I guess). The portable notation is the POSIX notation `[[:word:]]`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the pointer to the docs! It's more unusual than it should be to find good answers in ruby stdlib docs, sometimes people forget to look there. Actually they say [[:word]] includes punctuation too, if you want only 'letters' you want [[:alpha]], or [[:alnum]] for letters/numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use something like

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_ñáéíóú]
```

instead of `\w`