# How can I scan a ruby string with unicode characters?

Tags: ruby, regex, encoding

I say

```
"#gefährlicher #blödsinn".scan(/#(\w+)/).flatten
```

irb responds with:

```
"#gef��hrlicher #bl��dsinn".scan(/#(\w+)/).flatten
```

and I get

```
=> ["gef", "bl"]
```

which is obviously not what I want.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you are getting "question-mark" characters, your terminal isn't configured to display the characters correctly. Odds are good they are UTF-8, but, ISO-8859-1 or a variant of that is possible, or WIN-1252. Adjust your LOCALE settings or terminal, and those might go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976004/1427098), and the [Regex doducmentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html), `\w` is good only for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.  You want `\p{Word}`.

```
"#gefährlicher #blödsinn".scan(/#(\p{Word}+)/).flatten
# => ["gefährlicher", "blödsinn"]
```

That said, I don't know what you mean by "irb responds with..."  Obviously irb responds with the `=>` part...

Comment: There is a difference between what I type in and how irb interprets it, it seems. I type in the text with the umlauts and once I press enter it prints them out with those ? chars. Which is quite weird, because it does not seem to happen to you.

Comment: So this gives me the same result: ["gef", "bl"].

Comment: Maybe it is some readline hiccup and has nothing to do neither with ruby nor with regex…

Comment: There are a few possibilities I can think of... 1) What version of Ruby are you using? 2) If you're on a UNIXy system, what is your locale set to?

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for chinese characters like 축구하는시간 - any ideas?

Comment: @Kevin It seems to work for me with those characters... I guess you should post a new question with your exact code and version of Ruby.